# how to use nodatime for persian in c#?

Tags: persian, nodatime

`nodatime 1.3 released` , but i want to use `nodatime` in `c#` for Persian date time . 
how can i show Persian date time with Noda Time?

```
var london = DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb["Europe/London"];"
```

What must I do for Persian?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to explicitly use the Persian calendar.

For example:

```
var calendar = CalendarSystem.GetPersianCalendar();
var zone = DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb["Europe/London"];

var now = SystemClock.Instance.Now.InZone(zone, calendar);
// Now you can get the month, etc.
```

Or to create a `LocalDate` or `LocalDateTime`, just pass the calendar as the final argument in the constructor call:

```
var localDate date = new LocalDate(1393, 4, 17, calendar);
```

Note that that's using the London *time zone* in the Persian *calendar system*. Calendar systems and time zones are very different things. If you want the Tehran time zone, for example, you'd use:

```
var zone = DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb["Asia/Tehran"];
```

Comment: thanks a lot Jon ...

how can get name of mounth ?
for example   second mounth in persian calender is " اردیبهشت" .
how can i get name of day  
for example     sunday = "شـنـبـه"

Comment: @user3774926: You'd need to create a pattern with a CultureInfo with a calendar set to the relevant BCL calendar... we don't have CLDR support which would tell us that, I'm afraid.

Comment: excellent .... so i wish , will can get name of mounth and name of day and else ... for persian calender in next update of Nodatime ...
love you so much :)

Comment: @user3774926: I'm not sure what that comment means - if you use the right CultureInfo, you should be able to use normal Noda Time formatting. CLDR work is on my todo list...

Comment: @user3774926: I don't have time right now - I suggest you ask a new question, and if no-one else has answered it before tomorrow morning, I'll look then.

Comment: @user3774926: I've just checked, and unfortunately I don't think there are any `CultureInfo` values which use the Persian calendar or have it as an optional calendar. You might be best just creating your own hard-coded array for month names and day names.

Comment: thanks a lot ...
i with to see month names and day names in next version of Nodatime for Persian calender .
thanks Jon

Comment: @user3774926: We'll see. There will be lots of benefits from using CLDR data, but it's far from simple.