# any workaround or alternative to convert datetime to persian calendar?

Tags: c#, datetime, calendar

i'm developing a wp8.1 project that needs a conversion to persian calendar. it worked fine on my device. it was almost ready to publish but i faced a problem when testing with windows app certification kit.

i used [this](https://www.nuget.org/packages/PersianDate/) nuget package. it uses System.Globalization.PersianCalendar api but i get this error and errors like this.

```
  This API is not supported for this application type - Api=System.Globalization.PersianCalendar. Module=MSCORLIB, PUBLICKEYTOKEN=B77A5C561934E089. File=PersianDate.dll.
```

i know its because this api is not supported in wp8.1 but my question is what now?
is there any way to convert datetime to persian format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Jon Skeet's [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org/), as per this post: [how to use nodatime for persian in c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24637021/how-to-use-nodatime-for-persian-in-c)

Comment: @GrantWinney - It doesn't seem to be a duplicate IMO: this is a generic question about calendar support in .NET whereas the other post (which contains *an* answer to this question) is asking how to implement Persian calendar support in Noda Time.